# What is the meaning of an object having an uncertainty of velocity of 2 $\rm m/s$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, kinematics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis

In several questions we are given the uncertainty in velocity of an object and are asked to calculate the uncertainty in position of an object?

Well my doubt is that,as when we say that the uncertainty in position (of an let's say electron) is let's say 2 nm

We mean that the electron could be found anywhere within that 2 nanometer it could be present in 1.2 nm Or at 1.5 nm Or anywhere within that 2nm distance

But when we say that the uncertainty in velocity (of the electron) is let's say 2m/s (just for the sake of convenience)

Then what does that literally mean as it meant in the case of position

Comment: if you have downvote our answers, please tell us why so we can help identify your concern and try to help. As far as I can see, all three answers each address at least one of your concerns.

Comment: @MarkoGulin Votes (up/down) are anonymous, so you've been misinformed. I don't think if it would be a good idea if they were not. I can see a lot of mudslinging if that were the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that electron position is uncertain by $\pm 2\,\rm nm$, it means that whatever electron position you have calculated/measured, you may be wrong by 2nm offset. That is, in reality electron could be anywhere within 2 nm radius of your target position coordinate in position vector space.

Same goes about speed uncertainty. Whatever speed of electron you have calculated/measured, $2\,\rm m/s$ uncertainty means that in $v_x,v_y,v_z$ speed vector 3D phase space, electron speed fluctuates within radius of $2\,\rm m/s$ of your target value.

In addition, each vector component, may have it's own uncertainties. That is, it can be that
$$\Delta v_x \ne \Delta v_y \ne \Delta v_z,$$
due to the fact that your particle detector may be more sensitive to some measurement axis than others, etc.

Comment: And the downvote is for ?

Comment: Do not try to find a reason, and do not take it personal. Some community members are just eager with downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, I think we should identify users who on average makes a lot more downvotes than upvotes and restrict their access to voting, because positivity matters, IMHO. This should not be a site dedicated to express ones negative feelings in life. Such users should go somewhere else for their rants.

Comment: I agree about "positivity matters", and it also hurts me a bit to see a downvote for something I put effort on. I also wish users give more suggestions in comments and less downvotes, but people have different opinions. So do not worry about a downvote or two, let them have it :)

Comment: The uncertainty is not just "we know that the true value is in this range", but "with some certainty, the true value is in this range". It is an important distinction that your answer misses.

Comment: @user3725600 Physics is not about a word play, which seems you like very much. And if we look this way, there's not even a single fact in a universe for which we would be $100\%$ certain. So it does not makes sense to mention that we are just partially certain about something, because it inherently applies to everything.

Comment: This is more complicated than just wordplay. The "uncertainty" is always a property of a probability distribution and if you want to calculate it then you have to know what it means. 

You could have many definitions, e.g. the standard deviation of your distribution or the 95% confidence interval. Neither of those would give us the certainty (or near certainty) that the true value lies in $\langle x\rangle \pm \Delta x$. I am just saying that if you want to calculate something (and the question is about calculations) then you have to provide a specific definition.

Comment: Well, if you want my preference what uncertainty principle declaration I like most- is that standard deviations product is at least half of operators commutator: $\sigma _{A}\sigma _{B} \geq {\frac {1}{2}}\left|\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|$. And you misinterpreted me a bit. True value lies in $x_{true} = x_{measured} \pm \Delta x$, where $\Delta x$ is maximum error given by [uncertainty principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html).

Comment: The uncertainty principle gives you a lower bound for the uncertainty. It does not give you a "maximum error" in any way.

In most cases, if you want the $x_{true}$ to CERTAINLY lie in $x_{measured} \pm \Delta x$ your $\Delta x$ will explode to infinity.

Comment: Yes, lower bound, I know that. I do not target $100\%$ certainty, but instead had in mind that target parameters will be known within some confidence level. That's why wavefunction is more suitable for calculating states, because you can map state prediction results to exact confidence levels/probabilities. Anyway, the thing that we can't be sure that particle will sit at position $x$ within $\Delta x$ error, does not change the overall interpretation of uncertainty $\Delta x$ which was the OP principal question here.

Answer (score 2):

As Marko points out, this question is unclear, but I see you have the *uncertainty principle* as a tag.

If you mean that the electron has a velocity with uncertainty $\Delta v=2\ ms^{-1}$ and you want to find its corresponding position uncertainty, then you need to solve the following relation $$\Delta x\Delta p\ge \frac \hbar2$$ and since $p=mv$ then $\Delta p=m\Delta v$ so $$\Delta x\ge\frac{\hbar}{2m\Delta v}$$ where $m$ is the mass of the electron, then plug in the uncertainty in $v$ and Planck's constant.

Answer (score 1):

> In several questions we are given the uncertainty in velocity of an object and are asked to calculate the uncertainty in position of an object?

With any uncertainty, you need a function that translates *probability measure space* to *measurable space*, also called **distribution of the random variable**. Your example does not specify what exactly does the "uncertainty" of $2 \text{ m/s}$ mean.

Taking into account stochastic effects, the displacement is defined as

$$\Delta s = v \cdot t$$

where displacement $\Delta s$ and velocity $v$ are stochastic variables, while time $t$ is taken to be deterministic. The above equation can also be written as

$$\Delta \bar{s} + \Delta \tilde{s} = (\bar{v} + \tilde{v}) \cdot t$$

where (over)bar indicates mean (or expected) value of a stochastic variable, and tilde indicates variable uncertainty with zero mean. Since $\Delta \bar{s} = \bar{v} \cdot t$, from this it follows that the uncertainty in the displacement is

$$\Delta \tilde{s} = \tilde{v} \cdot t$$

---

We do not have any characterization of the velocity uncertainty (distribution). Let's discuss what happens for two common distributions: (i) uniform, and (ii) normal.

##### Uniform distribution

If the velocity follows *uniform distribution* it means that all velocity realizations lie within the $\bar{v} \pm 2 \text{ m/s}$ confidence interval, and every sample has equal chance of occurring. Since time is a *scalar variable*, the displacement uncertainty also follows uniform distribution and its confidence interval is $\Delta \bar{s} \pm (2 \cdot t) \text{ m}$ - again, any displacement sample from within this confidence interval *has equal chance of occurring*.

##### Normal distribution

Normal distributions are not bounded, i.e. the range of possible values goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. In that sense we usually specify uncertainty via **standard deviation** $\sigma$ - there is 68% chance that the stochastic variable realization will be within the $\bar{x} \pm 1\sigma$ confidence interval, 95.4% within the $\bar{x} \pm 2\sigma$, 99.7% within the $\bar{x} \pm 3\sigma$ etc.

If a stochastic variable $\tilde{x}$ follows normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, written as $\tilde{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $a \cdot \tilde{x}$ also follows normal distribution $a \cdot \tilde{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(a \mu, a^2 \sigma^2)$ where $a$ is (real) scalar.

In your example, if $2 \text{ m/s}$ equals one standard deviation ($1 \sigma$) of the velocity, then displacement deviation will be $(2 \cdot t) \text{ m}$, which means there is 68% chance of displacement occurring from within the $\Delta \bar{s} \pm (2 \cdot t) \text{ m}$ confidence interval.